# Paste Formula and Values across a range more efficiently?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add and copy a formula across a range of cells and then paste the values. Currently, the code I have works, BUT it takes too long to run. Do you know of a more efficient way to accomplish my goal? I am pasting the formula across 77,000 cells in ~3.69 minutes.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws As Worksheet, Lastrow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("CS1").Value = "Actual Bonus - Amount"
.Range("CS2").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table7[ID],table3[ID],Table7[Actual])"
.Range("CS2").Copy
.Range("CS3:CS" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can directly assign the formula to the entire range: `.Range("CS2:CS" & Lastrow).Formula = "=SUMIF(Table7[ID],table3[ID],Table7[Actual])"`

Comment: If an in-memory attempt at processing the sumifs is to be made, you are going to have to supply 15-20 rows of sample data.

Comment: Assigning the formula to the entire range was slower.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck isn't calculating the formula?

Comment: I think the bottleneck is in the calculation of the formula across the large number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .FillDown to put the formulas into the cells below without having to copy/paste.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws As Worksheet, Lastrow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("CS1").Value = "Actual Bonus - Amount"
.Range("CS2").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table7[ID],table3[ID],Table7[Actual])"
.Range("CS2:CS" & Lastrow).FillDown
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: .FillDown performed slightly better at ~3.31 minutes. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Give the solution @Kyle posted in the comment above a try and see if that is faster. Outside of that I don't know of any other more efficient way to add that many formulas.